# Is it possible to self-host a MVC 4 Application without IIS (not Web API)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

- Google will always find [how to self-host Web-API by use of
  HttpSelfHostServer or OWIN](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api) which is not feasable since that's for **MVC->Web API** and **not MVC**
- using [Hostable WEB Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378966/self-hosting-asp-net-mvc) is also not an option because you have to install IIS
- and the approach with CassiniDEv looks also not good for production (at least that's what [Sky Sanders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242897/sky-sanders) tells me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385006/which-build-of-cassini-should-i-choose-for-production-there-are-8-public-builds))

So, anybody else has and idea how to go about this?

[Edit]
  The reason for all those limitations are that it's not going to be a multi-user Web app but just a closed group of people will be accessing it and only on an Intranet so we were looking for a simple solution where we don't have to use any software setup outside our own (which has already update capabilities and handles up-/downgrades) and have full support/access to our already existing internal framework.

Comment: I don't believe so but why would you want to do this? IIS serves websites...

Comment: You seem to have ruled out a lot of possibilities, without explaining why. If you don't make it clear what your criteria are (i.e., *why* are all those options not feasible?), it's going to be very difficult for anyone to make useful suggestions.

Comment: You may try to create HTML page markup, script and style streams manualy by WCF service. It's a solution without IIS but without ASP.NET MVC Framework possibilities to.

Comment: Why can't you use IIS? What are you hoping to host the MVC site on?

Comment: @benl2k: it's not so much about "can't" but "don't" like or it has to be installed, set up, etc... if everything is inside my own proc then I have full control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after some "creative" googleing (we got inspired by [IronScheme](http://ironscheme.codeplex.com) - have a look at IronScheme.WebServer and IronScheme.Web.Runtime -> Web/Hosting)
and reverse engineering a sample MVC App (just look at the call stack and dig thrugh MSDN) we've found a possible solution.

we're going to utilize 
`System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost` for accessing our MVC app and `HttpListener`as our own lightweight only-for-our-purpose "webserver".